# AEM issue while spoof login

Tags: aem, spoofing

Spoof login redirecting to Unexpected Error (reutest.net) this page

image

have tried following things also

As soon as the instance is started, please open the "crx-quickstart" folder and go to the "bin" folder. Edit "quickstart.bat" file and update the port 4503 wherever 4502 is mentioned.
Now edit "start.bat" file and update the port 4503 wherever 4502 is mentioned. As well as update the mode to "publish" wherever "author" is mentioned.
Start the instance by using the windows batch file "quickstart.bat" present inside the "bin" folder of "crx-quickstart" folder.
Now go to "conf" folder that is just below the "bin" folder and open sling.properties file. Please enter sling.run.modes=publish,local on line# 17. Save and close the file.
Please restart the publisher instance.
Once the instance is re-started, open http://localhost:4503/system/console/bundles and login with the user name: admin and password: admin. Make sure all the bundles are in active state.
Later open http://localhost:4503/crx/de/index.jsp.
Once all the above steps are done open the path " /content/mytr/en/signin  " in CRXDE Lite as below

Add sling.run.modes=publish,local in sling.properties
Need to open configMgr and search for localauthsetup select 2nd checkbox
Open localhost:4503/userAdmin and create new user billuser1.fnr@mailinator.com
Pass password as admin admin and save
Give all permission to this user by double clicking on it
Open login page, spoof option will appear
If success dashboard not coming after executing above steps then please check for myacc in configMgr and make sure the user details service is pointing to RASI DEV env.

I have tried above methods also but spoof login is not working